# C++ testing void methods using gtest

Tags: c++, testing, void, googletest

I have just started to Unit Test in C++ using gtest, and I have a question regarding the testing of void methods.

Say I have a method void printNames(), which prints the names of all the students in a class.

1. Using testing, is there a way to check whether the method is printing the right names or not?
2. Or, is it even needed to test for such a thing?
3. I can make the method return string, and then test the returned string with a string that concatenates all the names of the students in the class. Would that be a "good" solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably write `printNames` to take an ostream as a parameter, possibly providing `std::cout` as a default value.

When you want to test, supply a reference to a `stringstream` instead, so you can capture the output and compare to an expected result.